# How to change numerical data to text in CSV file

Tags: python, python-3.x, csv, python-3.6

The below query is grabbing data and creating a CSV file, the issue that I am having is that the source called ‘SPLE’ stores data in the database with numbers of 0, 1, 50.

However in the CSV those numbers are being collected in the CSV and I would like somehow when creating the CSV those number to represent words such as,

0 = True

1 = False

50 = Pending

Could someone show me how this is done please, I have been struggling on this?
My Code:

from datetime import datetime
    from elasticsearch import Elasticsearch
    import csv

```
es = Elasticsearch(["9200"])


res = es.search(index="search", body=
                {
                    "_source": ["VT","NCR","N","DT","RD"],
                    "query": {

                        "bool": {
                            "must": [{"range": {"VT": {
                                            "gte": "now/d",
                                            "lte": "now+1d/d"}}},

                                {"wildcard": {"user": "mike*"}}]}}},size=10)


csv_file = 'File_' + str(datetime.now().strftime('%Y_%m_%d - %H.%M.%S')) + '.csv'


header_names = { 'VT': 'Date', 'NCR': ‘ExTime', 'N': 'Name', 'DT': 'Party', ' RD ': 'Period'}



with open(csv_file, 'w', newline='') as f:
    header_present  = False
    for doc in res['hits']['hits']:
        my_dict = doc['_source']
        if not header_present:
            w = csv.DictWriter(f, my_dict.keys())
            w.writerow(header_names,) 
            header_present = True
w.writerow(my_dict)




        w.writerow(my_dict)
```

The output in the CSV file is:

```
Date       RD        Venue
20171016    1       Central
20171016    1       Central
20171016    0       Central
20171016    0       Central
20171016    50      Central
20171016    0       Central
20171016    1       Central
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Change numerical data to text in CSV file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46784832/change-numerical-data-to-text-in-csv-file)

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you're making it a bit complicated, pandas is your friend.

```
import pandas as pd 

def SPLE_fix(sple):
    if sple == 0:
        return('True')
    elif sple == 1:
        return('False')
    else:
        return('Pending')


df=pd.read_csv('mycsvfile.csv')

df['SPLE'] = df['SPLE'].apply(SPLE_fix)

df.to_csv('newcsv.csv', index=False)
```

Output of newcsv.csv:

```
Date,SPLE,Venue
20171016,False,Central
20171016,False,Central
20171016,True,Central
20171016,True,Central
20171016,Pending,Central
20171016,True,Central
20171016,False,Central
```

**EDIT:**

For the pandas-free solution:

```
import csv

def SPLE_fix(sple):
    #just check for text in header
    try:
        sple[1]=int(sple[1])
    except:
        return(sple)

    #this part just changes the value
    if sple[1] == 0:
        sple[1] = 'True'
    elif sple[1] == 1:
        sple[1] = 'False'
    else:
        sple[1] = 'Pending'

    return(sple)


with open('mycsvfile.csv', 'r') as csvfile:
    data=csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=',')
    new_data=[SPLE_fix(row) for row in data]

with open('newcsv.csv', 'w', newline='') as csvfile:
    cwrite=csv.writer(csvfile, delimiter=',')
    cwrite.writerows(new_data)
```

This should get the same result. May not be the most efficient, but unless you are doing this a huge number of times, it shouldn't matter too much.

Comment: what if i can not install pandas on my computer because i am on a proxy?

Comment: I've added a method to get the same csv output without pandas.

Comment: unfortunately this is not working, i have a function that creates the CSV and gives it a file name of the data and time. so maybe that is causing the issue? let me update my post so you can see that part of the code

Comment: Can you also provide some info on what error you are getting?

Comment: there is not error, in the CSV the numbers have no converted in text. i have updated my code above for you to see the updated version. thanks

Comment: Is the code in your question a direct copy-paste from your script? It doesn't appear that you have implemented the fix I suggested, and it looks like there is a typo on ‘ExTime' in the header_names dict.